# Determine, whether element was wrapped around float-element

Tags: javascript, html, css, word-wrap

I have an image, which is `float: left;`

a `ul` tag is wrapped around this image. It is on the right-hand side of the image.

Custom bullets contained in the `ul` are partially overlapping the floating image.

When the `ul` is displaced to the right a little, this is fixed.

But, to do this, I need to determine, whether the `ul` is wrapped around this image.

How to do it ?

---

**Update 1:**

This code demonstrates the problem. It's true for standard bullets too, not only custom.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <title>Bullets overlapping example</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
 body {
  display: block;
  width: 400pt;
  margin: auto;
  border: solid thin gray;
 }
 img {
  float: left;
  width: 250pt;
 }
</style>
<body>
 <img src="http://www.hermann-uwe.de/files/images/blue_flower.preview_0.jpg" />
 <p>Bullets in a list below must be fixed someway, to prevent overlapping of float image</p>
 <ul>
  <li>Bullet of this list item overlaps left-hand-side image.</li>
  <li>This list item too</li>
  <li>And this ...</li>
 </ul>
 <div style="height: 6em;"></div>
 <p>This list should not be fixed, because it <b>does't wraps</b> the image</p>
 <ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
 </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can control specific behaviour for images inside ULs using CSS selectors:

```
ul img { ........ } /* This rule will apply only to images inside ULs */
```

It's possible in JavaScript, too, but this should be possible to sort out using pure CSS.

Comment: No, it's not my case. I have "list-style-image" property in CSS. It cannot be controlled this way

Comment: @Anton ahh I see, you need to address the `ul` if it contains an image?

Comment: No, i need to "Determine, whether element was wrapped around float-element" (see post title:). In other words, i need to apply certain CSS styles to only elements, which layout was altered by floating-elements.

Comment: @Anton ah. I don't think this can be done without hugely complex jQuery. But from the sound of it, this shouldn't be necessary: Maybe present an example of the overlap, this may well be fixable in the UL's CSS